# Geometric median (or Fermat-Weber problem), including continuous case

Tags: geometry, reference-request, optimization, discrete-geometry, median

For a finite set $X\subset \mathbb R^n$ the *geometric median* is defined as the point in $\mathbb R^n$ for which the sum of distances to all points of $X$ attains its minimum. Here is a wiki article:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_median

**Question 1.** Is there some standard contemporary *mathematical* book (or article or survey) that contains all the basic information on this topic? I was able to find the English translation of a classical article of Weizsfeld of 1937

http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10479-008-0352-z#/page-1

but I would like to learn of further sources.

**Question 2.** Clearly one can consider geometric medians of infinite sets, for example domains in $\mathbb R^n$ where one should minimize the integral of distance. What terminology is used in this case? Is this minimizing point still called the geometric median? Are there some nice sources?

**Question 2a.** I am interested in particular if there is some nice characterization of the geometric median (in the sense of Qustion 2) of a solid triangle in $\mathbb R^2$?